# Can't get KeyboardAvoidingView to move our of the way of inputs properly

Tags: android, ios, react-native

I've followed countless StackOverflow posts and other places and can't seem to find a solution to my issue or understand why this isn't working.

I've been able to distill it all down to a very simple Expo Snack that shows my problem of inputs clearly being behind the keyboard and it's not attempting to move at all

https://snack.expo.dev/@jordanr/keyboardavoidingview

I've in the past gotten this to work with no real issues but for some reason it's just not doing what I'm expecting it to do here

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap your content inside a `ScrollView` or use a `FlatList` (which is just a convenient wrapper around `ScrollView`).

You can add `keyboardVerticalOffset` to have a little bit more space.

```js
const KeyboardAvoidingComponent = () => {
  return (
    <KeyboardAvoidingView
      behavior={Platform.OS === "ios" ? "padding" : "height"}
      style={styles.container}
      keyboardVerticalOffset={20}
    >
      <ScrollView style={styles.inner}>
        <TextInput placeholder="test" style={styles.input} />
        <TextInput placeholder="test 2" style={styles.input} />
        <TextInput placeholder="test 3" style={styles.input} />
        <TextInput placeholder="test 4" style={styles.input} />
        <TextInput placeholder="test 5" style={styles.input} />
        <TextInput placeholder="test 6" style={styles.input} />
        <TextInput placeholder="test 7" style={styles.input} />
        <TextInput placeholder="test 8" style={styles.input} />
      </ScrollView>
    </KeyboardAvoidingView>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    overflow: "visible"
  },
  inner: {
    padding: 24,
    flex: 1,
    overflow: "visible"
  },
  header: {
    fontSize: 36,
    marginBottom: 48
  },
  input: {
    height: 40,
    borderColor: "#000000",
    borderBottomWidth: 1,
    marginBottom: 36,
    flex: 0
  },
  btnContainer: {
    backgroundColor: "white",
    marginTop: 12
  }
});

export default KeyboardAvoidingComponent;
```

Comment: Should I just always have my content in a scroll view even if I don't think it needs to be scrollable?